# Implement multi select dropdown with nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-5, nested-attributes

I am trying to implement multi select drop down but I am facing some issues.

1) In my case multiple drop down are coming I am not able to figure it out

2)If i edit any user all the tags which he has should  come selected default in multi select drop down.Also all the tags should come so that if he want to  update his tags or change his tags he can do it.

**User.rb**

```
 class User
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
      include Mongoid::Document
      include Mongoid::Timestamps

     devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
            :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable#, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]


      has_many :tags,dependent: :destroy
      accepts_nested_attributes_for :tags,allow_destroy: true

    end
```

**Tag.rb**

```
 class Tag
      include Mongoid::Document
      include Mongoid::Timestamps

       belongs_to :user

       field :name, :type => String

       field :created_at, :type => DateTime
       field :updated_at, :type => DateTime


    end
```

**users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!


    def index
        @users = User.all - [User.find_by(status: true)]
    end


    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])   
    end

    def edit
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end


    def update
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        if @user.update_attributes(user_params)
            redirect_to users_path      
        else
          render 'edit'
        end
    end

    private

        def user_params
          params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, tags_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy] )
        end


end
```

**users/edit.html.erb**

```
  <section class="content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-3">
         </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">

          <div class="box box-warning">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Update User</h3>
            </div>

            <div class="box-body">
             <%= form_for @user do |f| %>

                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>First Name</label>
                 <%= f.text_field :first_name, :required => 'required',:class => 'form-control' %>
                </div>



                 <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Tags</label>
                    <%= f.fields_for :tags do |user_tag| %>



                      <%= user_tag.select :name, User.find_by(id: params[:id]).tags.collect{|tag| [tag.name,tag.id]} ,{:prompt => "--select state--"},:class => 'form-control',multiple: true %>

                    <% end %>
                </div>

                <div class="box-footer">
                   <%= f.submit 'Submit',class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
              </div>


             <%end %>
            </div>

          </div>

        </div>

      </div>

    </section>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

According to [APIdoc](https://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.7/ActionView/Helpers/FormBuilder/fields_for)

> The block given to the nested fields_for call will be repeated for
>   each instance in the collection